# How & makes a reference to a string variable in C++?

Tags: c++, string, pass-by-reference

I am little confused about the use of & literal with strings. I see a big difference in the output of following two codes:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    char st[]="This is a Sample String";
    cout<<st[0];
    return 0;
}
```

> Output: T

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    char st[]="This is a Sample String";
    cout<<&st[0];
    return 0;
}
```

> Output: This is a Sample String

I know  & is used as a reference operator to pass the value by reference. But my question is how & actually works here.

Comment: The character "&" has several different meanings. The `&` operator applied to an expression creates a pointer, not a reference. The `&` you see in reference types is not an operator.

Comment: In the example you have shown, `&` is the "address of" operator.  It obtains the address of its operand, in this case the operand is `st[0]` and `&st[0]` gives the address of the first character in `st`.   `cout`s `operator<<()` is overloaded to accept a `const char *`, which it interprets as the address of the first character of a zero-terminated string (which is what `st` contains).

Comment: @Peter that should be an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

`Array of characters` is also called `string` in C++. And in `C++` if you want to print the Starting address of the string then it will not print the starting address of the string it will print the whole string.

The operator`&` have different meaning in different situation in `C++`. And the meaning of `&` is decided by its context(where it is using).

Comment: ‘*Array of characters is also called string in C++.*’ Debatable. A ‘string’ in C++ is something else to most people.

Comment: you are right but for the beginners the basic info is engouh... i don't want to make confuse to sahilsharma811 ..